# GDB: how do you measure the memory space available between the heap and stack?

Tags: c, memory, gdb

I'm reading a text on C about the memory segments available for use.  The text says the two highest segments are the heap and the stack, which grow towards each other.

```
Segments:
 ________
|Text (Machine code)
|________
|Data
|________
|BSS
|________
|Heap   (grows towards stack)
|
|
|Stack  (grows towards heap) 
|________
```

Creating a simple program to print out the memory locations of variables created in the lower four segments yields the following:

```
initialized in  | Hex Address | Decimal Value
Data        - 0x080497ec    134,518,764
BSS         - 0x080497f8    134,518,776
Heap        - 0x0804a008    134,520,840
Stack       - 0xbffff844    3,221,223,524
```

Is the interpretation that the heap and the stack have **~3 Billion** bytes to share between them?  The computer I'm working on only has 1 GB of memory, which makes me doubt the accuracy of this interpretation.

Comment: Is it one gigabyte of actual physical RAM, or one gigabyte of total _virtual_ memory?

Comment: What text is that? The layout of stack vs heap in the process' virtual space is *highly* system-dependent. Of course the size of the virtual address space doesn't mean much, either.

Comment: Ah, virtual address space vs. physical address space. Wasn't aware of the distinction.  Thanks.

Comment: This book sounds somewhat suspect.  There is no requirement in the standard that C even use a stack at all, much less how it is placed relative to the heap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's 3GB of address space there, it doesn't mean that it has to be mapped (most likely it isn't). It's just space, the operating system still has to map physical memory into that space when the program asks for it.

This kind of memory model you read about is pretty outdated. Modern operating systems have much more complex memory layouts, the heap doesn't have to grow linearly, stacks are sometimes located below everything else, and text and data don't necessarily have to be next to each other. Add in shared libraries, address space layout randomization and things get very funky.